# Quadratic extensions of $p$-adic fields

Tags: galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Now $\mathbb{Q}_p (\sqrt{p})$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Is it correct to think that elements of $\mathbb{Q}_p (\sqrt{p})$ are of the form $a+\sqrt{p}b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}_p$?

If that is the case, then the norm of $a+\sqrt{p}b$ is $a^2-pb^2$?

Comment: Yes, the calculation of the norm carries over from the global field side. Do observe that this extension is *ramified*, meaning that the $p$-adic valuation in this extension also takes half-integer values (with the usual normalization, see texts for better ways of formalizing the phenomenon)-

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen is this true also for the other two quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$? Can I write $a+\sqrt{n}b$ (or $a+\sqrt{np}b$) with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ and their norm is $a^2-nb^2$ (or $a^2-npb^2$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true for any quadratic extension of any field $K$ of characteristic not $2$: if $L/K$ is a quadratic extension, then $L=K(\sqrt{d})$, its elements are of the form $a+b\sqrt{d}$, and their norm over $K$ is $a^2-db^2$.

This is because the Galois conjugate of $x=a+\sqrt{d}b$ is $\bar{x}=a-\sqrt{d}b$, so the norm is $$N_{L/K}(x)=x\bar{x}=(a+\sqrt{d}b)(a-\sqrt{d}b) = a^2-db^2.$$

Comment: The reason every degree $2$ field extension is of that form (and we need characteristic $\neq 2$) is actually the quadratic formula a.k.a. "completing the square" method from high school. (I'm sure you know that, but maybe OP does not, and it's one of my favourite algebra facts and I have to point it out to everyone all the time.)

Comment: You don’t need to point it out to me, @TorstenSchoeneberg.

Comment: Fair point. I'll try to restrain my enthusiasm for the quadratic formula around those whose name is attached to some object I struggled to understand in grad school, @Lubin.